# How do I get a list of variables from the list of objects in drools

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-planner, drools-fusion, drools-flow

My rule is as follows:

```
when
  C : Company()
  $empname : List() collect from (Employee($empname : empname) from C.employees)
then
  System.out.println($empname);
```

The corresponding class:

```
public class Company {
  private List<Employee> employees;
  private Stringlocation;
}

public class Employee {
  private String empname;  
  private int empid;
}
```

With my code, I am only getting the Employee Objects but how do I get the `empnames` list?

Comment: Why don't you write a Java method `List<String> Company getEmpNames()`?

Answer (score 0):

It's preferable to implement simple data processing algorithms as methods in the class where they belong. Writing rules for this is possible but it's the wrong tool.

```
rule "employees"
when
   Company( $emps: employees )
   accumulate( Employee( $name: empname ) from $emps; 
               $name: collectList( $name ) )
then
   ... use List $name
end
```

Comment: rule "employees"
when
   Company( $emps: employees )
   accumulate( Employee( $name: empname ) from $emps; 
               $name: collectList( $name ) )
then
   ... use List $name
end

Comment: Here I have added a line $name contains "12345".   It's not working because List cannot be compared to the type in String .                                     I have also tried writing a function in drl file like                                      function boolean checkContains(List<> a, String b){                                      
  return a.contains(b);}

Comment: Don't post a new question in comments. Complete one question properly; then ask the next one as a new question.